# MemoryStream won't get updated C#

Tags: c#

Good morning,

I would need your help please.

1.) I create in my application ZipArchive objects from binary arrays which I get from a database.

2.) Within these ZipArchive objects I am supposed to remove certain files.

3.) Now I have to get these ZipArchive objects back into a MemoryStream or as a byte[]

this is the code I am using:

```
foreach (var zip in fileList.Reverse())
        {
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(zip.Content, true))
            {
                var zipFile = new ZipArchive(memStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update);

                foreach (var zipArchiveEntry in zipFile.Entries.Reverse())
                {
                    if (IsNecessary(zipArchiveEntry.Name) == false)
                    {
                        zipArchiveEntry.Delete();
                    }
                }

                zip.Content = zipFile.Entries.Count > 0 ? memStream.ToArray() : null;
            }

            if (zip.Content == null)
            {
                fileList.Remove(zip);
            }
        }
        return fileList;
```

At the moment this line:

```
zip.Content = zipFile.Entries.Count > 0 ? memStream.ToArray() : null;
```

gives me the un"cleaned" MemoryStream back, but I need the new one.

Have you guys some tipps or maybe a solution for me, how I can handle this with .NET? I have searched a while now, but it seams, that all just want to do it in the other direction.

PS: the delete works fine.

Sorry for the bad english and thank you in advance for your help. :-)

Comment: The code you have looks almost correct. You should just make sure that you close the original `zipFile` object before using the `memStream.ToArray()` method. Otherwise, the archive object won't have updated the stream. Just give the `zipFile` a `using` statement and keep the problematic line to outside that `using` block. If you need more help than that, you need to fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do and what the exact problem is.

Comment: (I find it ironic that you have the `using` statement on the `MemoryStream`, where it's useless, and do not have a `using` statement on the `zipFile`, where it's critical you have it.)

Comment: Thank you Peter, thats exactly what helped here. I did not know, that the zipFile had to be "closed", before it gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

*The code you have looks almost correct. You should just make sure that you close the original zipFile object before using the memStream.ToArray() method. Otherwise, the archive object won't have updated the stream. Just give the zipFile a using statement and keep the problematic line to outside that using block.*

This is the answer and did the job.